# show the entire contents of posts in an archive page as a table

Tags: posts, custom-post-type-archives, table

I am in trouble and am asking for your advice on how to proceed. I have created a custom post and inside I have created custom fields. I need to display all the posts as a table (one below the other) and use the acf fields as columns. I tried looking for some plugins but I find only plugins to create tables via csv or similar.

I so appreciate any form of help, thank you